# Using Google Play Services from a Service: alternate flow of events

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm working on a `Service` that will track the user's location using `LocationClient` from **Google Play Services**. Everything works fine, so now I want to consider alternate event flows like:

1. The user doesn't have Play Services on its phone
2. The user doesn't even have Google Play Store and is still using the Market app
3. How to handle any different case that those 2 above that will trigger `onConnectionFailed()`
4. The `Service` shouldn't be stopped unless certain condition has been met, so is `onDisconnect()` even going to be called (since `LocationClient#disconnect()` is not called)

Generally, when doing this inside an `Activity` you would just present a `Dialog` (from `GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog()` ) or similar to let the user know, but since this is a `Service` with no `Activity` related to it, how am I supposed to handle this kind of errors

Answer (score 1):

Create and show notification from your `Service`. When user clicks on it show `Activity` where errors/fails are described.